# How to find the approximate median from continuous data?

Tags: c, math, arduino

I am building a device to detect the change in environment noise by using Arduino and write in C.

Because the sound sensor will give me a sound level every second, how could I find the approximated median without storing all continuous data? And what is the best way to decide there is a change in current environment noise level?

Comment: Can you please tell from how many inputs you want to find median.

Comment: @Billa maybe infinite because there will be a input every second unless the device is turned off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it sounds like you want is called a *moving median* (very similar to a [*moving average*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)). This would be when you need to store the last `n` values in an array and compute the median.

Here's what this would look like:

```
int data[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int dataI = 0;

int sortedData[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

void pushNewData(int d) {
    data[dataI] = d;

    dataI++;
    if(dataI > 4) {
        dataI = 0;
    }
}

int median() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        sortedData[i] = data[i];
    }

    // Use a sorting algorithm here to sort sortedData

    return sortedData[3];
}
```

---

If you want to get the median of hundreds of hours of data, on the other hand, you have to store every data value. If this is your use case, I strongly recommend that you **use an average instead.** Since an average is just `sum / n`, you can only have two variables and add to them. Of course, you'll have to account for overflow.

---

Let's say you still want a median (for example, if you're worried about your data not being symetric or you're worried about outliers). In that case, you could easily build a histogram and estimate the median using that.

You'd do this by creating an array of ints. Index 0 would be for values `0-5`, index 2 would be for values `6-10`, and so on. (The size of each value range would vary based on your setup.) Each time a new data point comes in, you would check which "bucket" (value range) the point falls into and you would increment the corresponding counter in that array.

It's easy to approximate your median from this data. Let's say you extracted this data:

```
Values 00-05: 1
Values 06-10: 7
Values 11-15: 8
Values 16-20: 2
Values 21-25: 1
Values 26-30: 5
```

Since n = 24, the median would be n=12. The 12th data point would be in the `11-15` range, so your median would be between 11 and 15.

Instead of ranges of 5, you could easily do ranges of 3 or of 1 with the same effect. Just beware of overflow and memory usage: you should use an array of unsigned longs in addition to making sure to not use too many buckets.

Answer (score 1):

Do a search for "find running median".  Search stackoverflow first.  There are a number of approaches, with suitability based on known characteristics of your data.

One simple approach would be to create an integer array, say 20 elements of equal range.  As each sample is taken, map the value to the range set, and add 1 to that counter.  On completion, the counter values could then be analysed to calculate an approximated median.

You may need to try a few different approaches in order to determine what works best for you.